# How to set the object value in ng-model, in select tag, from an object array. and is there an easy way to add filters on ng-options,

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my html :

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

     {{loadDataSubject('${subjectList}')}}
     {{loadDataTopic('${topicList}')}}



<h1 class = "bg-success" style="color: red;text-align: center">Fill in the below details for Question Template : -</h1> <br> 

<div class="container">

  <form method="get" action="createTemplate">
    <div class="form-group">

    <label for="sel1">Topics (select one):</label>
     <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedTopic" ng-options="topic.name as topic.name for topic in topics">
    </select> <br>

    {{selectedTopic}}

      <label for="sel1">Subject (select one):</label>

     <select name="subject" value= "" class="form-control" ng-model ="selectedSubject" ng-options="sub.name as sub.name for sub in subjects">
    </select> <br>

      <label for="sel1">Negative marking:</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="negativeMarks">
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
      </select> <br>

      <label>Reference Book:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ref" required>
      <label for="sel1">Number of Questions:</label>
       <input type="number" class="form-control" name="questionCount" required><br>

       <input class ="bg-primary" type="submit" value="submit and download template">

    </div>
  </form>
</div>


</body>
```

and here is the script :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.subjects = [];
    $scope.topics = [];
    $scope.selectedSubject = {};
    $scope.selectedTopic = {};


    $scope.loadDataSubject = function(subjectList) {
          $scope.subjects = JSON.parse(subjectList);
        };

    $scope.loadDataTopic = function(topicList) {
          $scope.topics = JSON.parse(topicList);
        };  
});
```

I want to add a filter to options to selectonly the subjects of selected Topic, 
something like filter : selectedTopic.id

Error is

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…turn%20b(f%2Cc%2Ce)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A74%2C%22oldVal%22%3A68%7D%5D%5D
    at angular.js:38
    at r.$digest (angular.js:15934)
    at r.$apply (angular.js:16160)
    at angular.js:1679
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4523)
    at c (angular.js:1677)
    at yc (angular.js:1697)
    at Zd (angular.js:1591)
    at angular.js:29013
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3057)
```

before that i want to bind the value of object to ng-model, while the objects name gets binded. Please help me, I'm new with this.

subjects: 
[{"subjectId":1,"name":"ComputerScience","code":"CS"},{"subjectId":2,"name":"Computer Basics","code":"CS","documentUrl":"None"},{"subjectId":3,"name":"Computer Basics","code":"CS","documentUrl":"None"},{"subjectId":4,"name":"php","code":"PHP01","documentUrl":"None"},{"subjectId":5,"name":"JAVA","code":"JAVA01","childSubjects":[{"subjectId":6,"name":"Core Java","code":"JAVA02","parentSubject":5,"childSubjects":[{"subjectId":8,"name":"Thread","code":"JAVA04","parentSubject":6},{"subjectId":9,"name":"Object Class","code":"JAVA05","parentSubject":6},{"subjectId":10,"name":"Inheritance","code":"JAVA06","parentSubject":6}]},{"subjectId":7,"name":"Advance Java","code":"JAVA03","parentSubject":5,"childSubjects":[{"subjectId":11,"name":"Servlet","code":"JAVA07","parentSubject":7}]}]},{"subjectId":12,"name":"Computer Basics","code":"CS","documentUrl":"None"}]

topics:

[{"topicId":1,"name":"Technical","code":"TECH","isSubjectsRelated":1,"description":"All Technical subjects","isActive":1,"subjects":[{"subjectId":1,"name":"ComputerScience","code":"CS"},{"subjectId":1,"name":"ComputerScience","code":"CS"}]},{"topicId":2,"name":"GATE","code":"GATE","isSubjectsRelated":1,"description":"GATE exam","isActive":1,"subjects":[]},{"topicId":5,"name":"Programming","code":"PROG","isSubjectsRelated":0,"description":"Coding skills","isActive":1,"subjects":[{"subjectId":5,"name":"JAVA","code":"JAVA01"}]}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Topics select-box to this

```
 <label for="sel1">Topics (select one):</label>
     <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedTopic" ng-options="topic as topic.name for topic in topics">
    </select>
```

And similarly for subject selectbox.Check out [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/TvIgvEEshocu8Cr0lWqN?p=preview) plunker.

Comment: angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…turn%20b(f%2Cc%2Ce)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A74%2C%22oldVal%22%3A68%7D%5D%5D
    at angular.js:38
    at r.$digest (angular.js:15934)
    at r.$apply (angular.js:16160)
    at angular.js:1679
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4523)
    at c (angular.js:1677)
    at yc (angular.js:1697)
    at Zd (angular.js:1591)
    at angular.js:29013
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3057)

Comment: this error you are getting is because of some faulty structure of you Topic or Subjects object.

Comment: I want to add if the programmatically changed ng-model value doesn't update UI, use **track by topic.id** in ng-options